# Ошибка во время отладки

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, mobile-development

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi Note 7 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\src\projects\mealway\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\satyb\.gradle\caches\6.7\scripts\1fnwrr8g4rohfp291nvlxj5qe).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 60

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 859ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

ЯП Dart/Flutter.

Проект создал только что, и хотел сделать отладку на телефоне. Выдал такую ошибку. Уже пробовал установить новую версию Gradle, не помогло.

Comment: Добавь вывод команды `flutter doctor`, если в нем есть сообщения о проблемах.

Comment: Похоже, что у вас установлен **Java SDK 16**? Поставьте более старую версию, например 14.